# Why do we use trees and not dictionary or hashmaps for Huffman Compression?

Tags: dictionary, tree, compression, huffman-code

Why do we create a Huffman Tree and not just use a dictionary to compress the file? I believe we could do the same using a dictionary but was unable to find an implementation of Huffman Compression using only a dictionary. Neither was able to answer why using a dictionary is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if you can do LZ77 compression (referencing matching strings in the preceding uncompressed data), and *not* following that with Huffman or other entropy coding, then yes you can and [lz4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ4_(compression_algorithm)) does that.

Your phrase "Huffman Compression using only a dictionary" does not make any sense.

Comment: I phrased my question poorly.

I wanted to know the use of Huffman Tree in compression when a simple dictionary, storing the mapping would have done the trick. (still prioritizing more occurring elements shorting string). 

What I had overlooked was the fact that now my "fixed length" code had become "variable length" and now when I had to decompress the file, I would in some way need to the difference between "00" and "0, 0". Which Huffman solved using prefix code.

All I wanted to know was why the tree is important. Apologies for framing the question poorly.

Comment: Please rephrase your question by editing it.